# Win7 32 bit, installing Touch Screen

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

I have a Flattron T1910 touch screen that I am trying to install on a legacy 32bit Win7 machine.

The mointor is connected trough both serial and USB, T1910 monitor driver is installed.
TabletPC feature is installed. The blasted thing does not work.

I tried downloading several Microsoft Update Catalog files that might be for it (or related), but regradless if I try Command Prompt of Power Shell DISM installations, they fail every time (getting system cannot find the file specified error, path is correct ... none of those  updates have any KB number I can find)
I have tried re-naming the files, moving them around. I tried extracting the catalog and installing trough device manager, but it always says I already have the newest drivers for the monitor, and input devices... I'm not even sure where they should go.. I assume USB input devices, but the two that show up are keyboard and mouse.

SEE:

https://i.postimg.cc/wMzqpS2G/p1.jpg

https://i.postimg.cc/5ymxNnkN/p2.jpg

I'm at the end of my wits here...